# How to create a dispose pattern for out parameters (Message IDE0068)

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

Consider code like this:

`System.Data.DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

Code like this will likely give a message in the error list in Visual Studio: **IDE0068 Use recommended dispose pattern to ensure that object created by '...' is disposed on all paths: using statement/declaration or try/finally**. So wrapping it in a using block will ensure the `dt` instance is disposed of.

But what about this case:

`SomeFunction(out DataTable dt);`

How to dispose `dt` in this case? Wrapping it in a using block does not seem to be accepted:

```
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
/*dt needs to be initialised above otherwise this line won't compile*/
  SomeFunction(out DataTable dt);
  /* Above line: cannot use dt as ref or out variable because it is a 'using variable'*/
}
```

Can `using` be used at all here or do I need to call something like `dt?.Dispose();` at the end of the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the `using` block accepts an expression, not just a declaration, so you can wrap it immediately after you get it.

```
SomeFunction(out var dt);
using (dt)
{
    // Your logic here...
}
```